# Function to map points inside a rotated rectangle.

Tags: functions, trigonometry

The problem we are trying to solve is one from an app but this is not really a programming problem which is why I'm asking here.

We are mapping user locations inside a football field on a map. The football field will be a real world football field and could be rotated at any angle.

So the corners A, B, C, D could be at...

```
A = (0, 0) 
B = (8, 8) 
C = (12, 5) 
D = (4, -3)
```

(These are not an exact rectangle but they act as an illustration, the actual rectangle would be an exact rectangle).

We would then like to display the tracked locations inside a football field shown the right way up in the phone.

With the points...

```
A' = (0, 0)
B' = (0, 11.3)
C' = (5, 11.3)
D' = (5, 0)
```

What we are looking for is a function to map any point p at position (x, y) inside the original football field to a point p' at position (x', y')

Please let me know if I need to provide more information but I think I've covered everything.

Comment: Are there no transformations other than rotation? In other words, can we rely on the rectangle $R$ to be the same size as rectangle $R'$?

Comment: @user164385 yes assume they are the same size. Even if they aren't in the final product we can transform easily between rects of different scale but the same rotation. Thanks

Comment: And is $A$ always the origin?

Comment: How are you mapping the rectangle that represents the field to the screen? The same transformation should take care of the user locations as well. Or is the field to screen mapping what you’re asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've answered assuming $A$ is always $(0,0)$. The algorithm is only slightly more complex if this is not the case. For notation, I'm using $A_x$ to be the $x$-coordinate of $A$ and so on.

Consider your points as vectors, so that $P = \begin{bmatrix}P_x \\ P_y\end{bmatrix}$. Then to find $P'$, you just want to multiply $P$ by the appropriate rotation matrix, $$P' = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\ \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta)\end{bmatrix} P = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(\theta) \cdot P_x -\sin(\theta) \cdot P_y \\ \sin(\theta) \cdot P_x + \cos(\theta) \cdot P_y \end{bmatrix}. $$

Finding the angle of rotation is especially easy if one of the sides of your rectangle (in this case, $A'D'$) lies along the $x$ axis and $A$ stays fixed at the origin: you need only to find the angle of $D = \begin{bmatrix} D_x \\ D_y \end{bmatrix}$ as a vector (negated, since you're rotating from $R$ to $R'$ rather than from $R'$ to $R$). Since $A$ is at the origin, this is $$\theta = -\tan (D_y / D_x)$$

Comment: Excellent! I knew it should be easy but was getting caught up in trigonometry and pythagorus etc... Thanks :D